# CDF's of Two Binomial Distributions with the Same Mean and Different Probabilities

Tags: pr.probability, binomial-distribution

Suppose we have two binomial random variables $X_i \sim B(\frac{a}{p_i},p_i)$ and $X_j \sim B(\frac{a}{p_j},p_j)$, where $a$ is a positive integer, and both $\frac{a}{p_i}$ and $\frac{a}{p_j}$ are integers. Assume $p_i > p_j$. In particular, we have $E[X_i] = E[X_j] = a$.

Let $F_{X_i} (x)$ and $F_{X_j} (x)$ denote the CDF's of $X_i$ and $X_j$, respectively. It seems true (with an example in the image below) that $F_{X_i} (x) < F_{X_j} (x)$ for $x < a$ and $F_{X_i} (x) > F_{X_j} (x)$ for $x > a$. Is there a simple way to prove it (or, is this result somewhat established in literature)?

[image: Example]

Comment: crossposted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3969967/87355 ---  please don't do that, in particular not without disclosing it, to avoid wasteful duplication of efforts.

Comment: Thanks for your response! One thing I find tricky here is that in the problem set-up $N$ actually changes with $p$ (i.e., $N  = \frac{a}{p}$ for some constant $a$). Does the derivative method still apply here or maybe more tricks would be needed?

Comment: @messi22: Yes, you are right, I didn't quite answer the question you asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This  result is known. See e.g. Corollary 4 in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0167715220302042) or its [arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.01125).

Comment: Thanks very much for your help!